# crop text to fit in column - html helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a html helper that can crop text (say, for an actionlink) so that it fits into a table column without wrapping? I remember reading about a helper that crops and then adds ... to the end, but cannot find it again. Otherwise, I will just make my own helper.

Comment: I also have the feeling I was reading a blog post doing just that, but I also can't find it immediately. There is one issue though with "just trimming" the amount of characters. The problem here is that not every character takes the same amount of pixels on the screen (except if you're using [monospace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) fonts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. There is an example of one in the ASP.NET MVC Music Store tutorials which is where you may have seen it.

Copied from the [tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/49578296/27/Using-a-custom-HTML-Helper-to-truncate-text):

```
public static stringTruncate(this HtmlHelperhelper,string input,int length)
{ 
    if(input.Length <= length)
    { 
        returninput;
    } 
    else 
    { 
        returninput.Substring(0, length) +"...";
    }
}
```

Comment: That was indeed the sample I remember bumping into once :) As stated in my comment above, you will probably need to truncate enough characters to ensure it works fine. If you have the requirement to make it _exactly_ fit the width, then you'll have to take another approach. I once wrote something like that.. let me know if you need some code (js solution).